# Samsung s-planner as interface to google calendar, miss 3-day layout

Tags: calendar

S-planner app lost 3-days layout after last update.

That made me cry.

I want to solve it with anyway, change calendar app, or rollback to old s-planner version, or something else?

Please point me to any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have saved the previous version's `.apk`, you can re-instate it. That's why I have [AppMonster Pro Backup Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.appmanagerpro) installed and running: it captures each and every `.apk` installed, so I can always revert to a previous version.

If you don't have the old `.apk` available, and you are talking about a free app, you can check [Android Drawer](http://www.androiddrawer.com/about/) for a previous version's `.apk`. Download it, make sure you have [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources) enabled in your settings, and launch the `.apk` e.g. from a file explorer. This should install the (old version of the) app without you losing any data.

Comment: Thank you alot. Unfortunately I have not previous apk. and Adroid Drawer did not save "S Planner" too.

Comment: If you find someone else who has not updated, he/she could still use *AppMonster* to catch the `.apk`. *AppMonster* saves the files to SDCard, so it should then be easy to pick it up and make it available to you. You could also see if [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) or [Aptoide](http://www.aptoide.com/) have it.